# Projecting ellipses onto circles using homographies

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography

I am relatively new to computer vision, and I am experimenting with extracting a clock/dial face from an image.

I managed to fit an ellipse onto the dial, and I wanted to fix the perspective such that the dial would face the camera directly.
Essentially, I wanted to project an ellipse onto a circle.

I found online that homographies are normally used to accomplish this task.

I tried following the OpenCV tutorial on homographies, but I am having problems with the source poorly matching the destination.

Reading similar questions, a perfect projection seems impossible since perspective-projected circles are not really ellipses.
However, I am not looking for a mathematically exact projection, but even the simplest cases I have seem to produce bad results (see example 4 in the images below).

Here are four example input images on which I annotated the ellipses (red), unit circles (blue), source points (yellow), and destination points (cyan) (note: the centers are annotated but are not used to compute the homography).
[Annotated input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1g4J.png)

However, after applying the homography computed using OpenCV (I got the same exact results using Scikit), the ellipses are not projected well onto the unit circles.
[Homography results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4bZz.png)

I also tried using more than 4 points to compute the homography, but again, the results were identical.

Here is the code I used:

```py
def persp_transform(orig):
    img = orig.copy()

    ellipses = find_ellipses(img)
    ellipse = ellipses[0] # Use the largest one

    center_x = ellipse[0]
    center_y = ellipse[1]
    center = np.array([center_x, center_y])
    width = ellipse[2]
    height = ellipse[3]
    angle = ellipse[4]
    minor_semiaxis = min(width, height)/2
    major_semiaxis = max(width, height)/2

    # Translate the image to center the ellipse
    img_center = np.array([img.shape[0]//2, img.shape[1]//2])
    translation = center - img_center
    M = np.float32([[1, 0, -translation[1]], [0, 1, -translation[0]]])
    img = cv.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

    # Draw ellipse before projection
    rr, cc = ellipse_perimeter(img_center[0], img_center[1], int(major_semiaxis), int(minor_semiaxis), orientation=angle, shape=img.shape)
    draw_ellipse(img, rr, cc, color=0, thickness=10)
    
    def sin(a): return np.sin(np.deg2rad(a))
    def cos(a): return np.cos(np.deg2rad(a))
    
    # Source points around the ellipse
    num_points = 5
    rotation = np.array([[np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)], [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]])
    from_points = np.array([[major_semiaxis*sin(a), minor_semiaxis*cos(a)] for a in np.linspace(0, 360, num_points)]) @ rotation + img_center
    from_points = from_points.astype(np.float32)

    # Destination points around a centered circle
    to_radius = int((min(img.shape[:2]) / 2) * 0.8)
    to_points = np.array([[to_radius*sin(a), to_radius*cos(a)] for a in np.linspace(0, 360, num_points)]) @ rotation + img_center
    to_points = to_points.astype(np.float32)

    # Draw ellipse center and source points before projection
    cv.circle(img, (img_center[1], img_center[0]), 20, (255, 255, 0), -1)
    for fp in from_points:
        cv.circle(img, (int(fp[1]), int(fp[0])), 20, (255, 255, 0), -1)
    
    # Compute homography and project
    M, _ = cv.findHomography(from_points, to_points, cv.RANSAC, 5.0)
    img = cv.warpPerspective(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

    # Draw target unit circle and destination points after projection
    cv.circle(img, (img_center[1], img_center[0]), to_radius, (0, 0, 255), 20)
    cv.circle(img, (img_center[1], img_center[0]), 20, (0, 255, 255), -1)
    for tp in to_points:
        cv.circle(img, (int(tp[1]), int(tp[0])), 20, (0, 255, 255), -1)

    return img
```

## EDIT 1

Here are the 4 raw example images I used as input: [GDrive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/109LI7AdkygcZAT1mbpmntnrns7WZLMMt/view?usp=sharing)

To fit the ellipses, I use the method proposed in [AAMED](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8972900), which can be found on GH [here](https://github.com/Li-Zhaoxi/AAMED).

I manually played with the input parameters until I found satisfactory ones since I didn't need to find all the ellipses in the image, only the main ones.

My ellipse finding code looks like this:

```py
def find_ellipses(orig, scale=0.3, theta_fsa=20, length_fsa=5.4, T_val=0.9):
    img = cv.resize(orig.copy(), None, fx=scale, fy=scale)
    gray_image = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    aamed = AAMED(img.shape[0]+1, img.shape[1]+1)
    aamed.setParameters(np.deg2rad(theta_fsa), length_fsa, T_val)
    ellipses = aamed.run_AAMED(gray_image)
    aamed.release()

    ellipses = sorted(ellipses, key=lambda e: ellipse_area(e), reverse=True)
    ellipses = [np.array(e) / scale for e in ellipses]

    return ellipses
```

Then I use `skimage.draw.ellipse_perimeter(...)` to impose the largest ellipse on the image.

## Edit 2

I tried to better visualize the homography and narrowed down the issue possibly to `cv.warpPerspective(...)`.

Firstly, I color-coded each point pair to check that I was mapping the right pairs: [Color-coded points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dxEe.png)

Then, I computed the homography and individually projected each source point using `cv.perspectiveTransform(...)` without warping the image to see where they would end up, and they seemed to be projected properly: [Projected points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwOZn.png)

However, when I then use `cv.warpPerspective(...)` to project the image, the projection is inconsistent with the result from `cv.perspectiveTransform(...)`: [Wrong projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYuUG.png)

Comment: sobasically you want  to get the circular shape around the clock ?

Comment: they _are_ ellipses but the 2D center of the ellipse is different from the projected 3D center of the circle. -- calculating homography from an ellipse to a circle has degrees of freedom you can't recover from the ellipse+circle info. -- you need more info. can you assume a specific appearance of the dial face?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Essentially yes, with the idea that I can correct for the perspective distortion and later segment it removing the background

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Unfortunately, I cannot assume any sort of specific appearance for the dial, except probably for the presence of 1 or more indicator hands, but again, their shape is also not known. 
To make the centers of the ellipse and the circle match, I have also tried not shifting the image to the center of the ellipse and computing the homography, adding the centers to source and destination points, but with the same results.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The closest thing I have found to what you are saying is this [paper](https://projet.liris.cnrs.fr/imagine/pub/proceedings/ICIP-2014/Papers/1569894217.pdf) by Luis Alvarez and Vicent Caselles, but I am not sure if I could use just the indicator hand to replicate their method.

Comment: if you only have an ellipse, this is not solvable. that paper deals with a reasonably flat surface. your dials are anything but flat.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The dial in the picture is not perfectly flat, but I don't need a perfect projection. A decent approximation is enough.
The outputs of images 2 and 4 are a good example of a satisfactory result, and even 1 is almost there. Image 3 is the main problem.

Comment: the third one that looks like it's getting stretched even more, instead of being straightened? that might be happening with the other pictures too but you don't notice because they're mostly straight already and the effect is proportionally small

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I see, that makes sense, unfortunately, I don't have any other feature I could reliably use.
If using homographies is not the right way, what other method would you suggest?
I would possibly like to avoid using resource-intensive machine-learning techniques, but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: homography on the four cardinal points should be good enough but it'll mostly be something affine. the difference becomes smaller the further the object is from the camera. you should be able to get reasonably round results. there must be an issue in your code. perhaps the matrix needs inverting, or not-inverting. try swapping the point sets you pass to findHomography. if you have exactly 4 points, you can call getPerspectiveTransform directly.

Comment: Post the input images individually without markings and not grouped.

Comment: Post your code for processing the input image and fitting the ellipse to the clock image. How did you extract the clock from the background.

Comment: @fmw42 I edited my response to add what you asked for.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried all your suggestions, but none worked.
Predictably, swapping the points is equivalent to inverting the matrix, and the two operations cancel out.
FindHomography also behaves identically to getPerspectiveTransform when used with 4 points (I made sure no 3 points were colinear).

I even tried color-coding the points to make sure I was matching the correct source-destination pairs.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried further experiments to better understand what the projection does. I have edited my question with the new results. Please take a look.

Comment: now that looks like you swapped x and y somewhere. your code uses lots of indexing. perhaps use more "destructuring bind", i.e. `(x,y) = point` and `(i, j) = indices` kinda expressions. that's all I can guess without running your code. you might want to present a [mre] with an input image, the code containing hardcoded coordinates, so you can rip out the ellipse fit code and focus on the code that's causing trouble.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Here is a [MRE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10m1NF_jLQkprSNASt4r0kp2xmVsh9pKK/view?usp=sharing).
It is a .zip containing an example image and a Python notebook.
Running the notebook will produce two images corresponding to the last two images I shared in my second edit.

I tried tidying up the code as you suggested, eliminating random indices. However, due to inconsistencies between libraries, mainly OpenCV, which sometimes requires coordinates to be sapped, when drawing, there are still some cases where I have to manually fiddle with the x-y order (note the [::-1]).

Comment: `@Mike` You did not answer my question properly. I asked to see your full resolution input image without markings by itself, not connected to 3 other images. I also asked how you processed that image to find the ellipse. Did you threshold and get contours?  Where is the code for doing whatever you did in processing the input to find the ellipse?

Comment: @fmw42 The answers to what you asked should be under Edit 1.
Specifically, you asked for the full-resolution input images, which can be found on Google Drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/109LI7AdkygcZAT1mbpmntnrns7WZLMMt/view?usp=sharing).

Regarding finding the ellipse, I used the Python bindings for the AAMED method linked in the edit. You can see the whole function in the edit as well.
Preprocessing consists only of scaling and converting to grayscale since AAMED already performs all the necessary steps (e.g., thresholds and contours).

Let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: `@Mike`.  Sorry, I was looking at EDIT 2

Comment: please don't edit your question to add an answer/solution. this site has a question-answer format. you are allowed and encouraged to post an answer yourself.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the suggestion. I will remove the solution part from my question and publish it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one attempt in Python/OpenCV. The idea is the get the ellipse. Then get the 4 points on the ellipse that corresponds to the min and max semi-major radii. Then get the 4 corresponding points on a circle or radius equal to the max semi-major radii. Then compute the homography for the two sets of 4 corresponding points. Finally warp the image.

- Read the input
- Read the ellipse mask
- Get the contour of the mask
- Fit and ellipse to the contour
- Compute the 4 points on the ellipse from the ellipse parameters
- Compute the 4 points on the circle using the max semi-major radius
- Get the homography between the two sets of points
- Warp the input image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

Ellipse Mask (fit manually in Photoshop):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('ex_4.jpg')

# read ellipse mask as grayscale
mask = cv2.imread('ex_4_mask.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# get ellipse contour
contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw contour on black background
mask2 = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask2, [big_contour], 0, 255, 1)

# fit ellipse to mask contour
points = np.argwhere(mask2.transpose()>0)
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(points)
(cx,cy), (d1,d2), angle = ellipse

# draw ellipse
ellipse = img.copy()
cv2.ellipse(ellipse, (int(cx),int(cy)), (int(d1/2),int(d2/2)), angle, 0, 360, (0,0,255), 4)

# correct angle
if angle > 90:
    angle = angle - 90
else:
    angle = angle + 90
print('center: (', cx,cy, ')', 'diameters: (', d1, d2, ')', 'angle:', angle)

# get 4 points from min and max semi-major radii
r1 = min(d1,d2)/2
r2 = max(d1,d2)/2

x1 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle))*r2 )
y1 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle))*r2 )
x2 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle+180))*r2 )
y2 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle+180))*r2 )
x3 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle+90))*r1 )
y3 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle+90))*r1 )
x4 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle+270))*r1 )
y4 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle+270))*r1 )

print('x1,y1:', x1, y1)
print('x2,y2:', x1, y1)
print('x3,y3:', x1, y1)
print('x4,y4:', x1, y1)

# input points from ellipse
input_pts = np.float32([[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]])

# output points from circle of radius = max semi-major radii
ox1 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle))*r2 )
oy1 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle))*r2 )
ox2 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle+180))*r2 )
oy2 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle+180))*r2 )
ox3 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle+90))*r2 )
oy3 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle+90))*r2 )
ox4 = np.intp( cx + math.cos(math.radians(angle+270))*r2 )
oy4 = np.intp( cy + math.sin(math.radians(angle+270))*r2 )

cx = np.intp(cx)
cy = np.intp(cy)
r2 = np.intp(r2)
ellipse_pts = ellipse.copy()

# draw white circle on copy of ellipse
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (cx,cy), r2, (255,255,255), 4)

output_pts = np.float32([[ox1,oy1], [ox2,oy2], [ox3,oy3], [ox4,oy4]])

# draw output points on copy of ellipse image
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (ox1,oy1), 16, (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (ox2,oy2), 16, (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (ox3,oy3), 16, (0,255,0), 4)
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (ox4,oy4), 16, (0,255,0), 4)


# draw input points on copy of ellipse image
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (x1,y1), 12, (255,0,0), -1)
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (x2,y2), 12, (255,0,0), -1)
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (x3,y3), 12, (255,0,0), -1)
cv2.circle(ellipse_pts, (x4,y4), 12, (255,0,0), -1)

# get homography when only 4 pts
h = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(input_pts, output_pts)

# warp image
result = cv2.warpPerspective(img, h, (img.shape[1],img.shape[0]))


# save results (compress to fit 2Mb limit on this forum)
cv2.imwrite('ex_4_ellipse.jpg', ellipse, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 85])
cv2.imwrite('ex_4_ellipse_pts.jpg', ellipse_pts, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 85])
cv2.imwrite('ex_4_ellipse2circle.jpg', result, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 85])

# show results
cv2.imshow('ellipse', ellipse)
cv2.imshow('ellipse_pts', ellipse_pts)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Ellipse on input:

[image]

Ellipse with points and circle:

[image]

Warped Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I rewrote my whole script from scratch and used yours to double-check my results along the way.
From what I could understand, I was using OpenCV correctly, and the problem was related instead to some swapped coordinates or improperly ordered points as suggested by Christoph Rackwitz.
I am pretty sure the issue arose because of how OpenCV and PLT treat coordinates, where sometimes they are swapped and sometimes not.
I stopped using PLT to draw anything on the image like you did and it made the code much clearer and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Christoph Rackwitz and fmw42, I tracked down the issue to improperly formatted coordinates.
Be it swapped x and y positions or badly ordered points in arrays.
I attribute the cause to inconsistencies in the order of the coordinates required by OpenCV and PLT, which can be confusing.

Regardless, not using PLT for drawing on the image and relying completely on OpenCV made the final code much clearer, and the issue is not present in the final rewrite.

Another imprecision I noticed is that the rotation matrix computed explicitly using Numpy gave worse results than the one obtained using `cv.getRotationMatrix2D(...)`, which further improved the final result.

I guess if there needs to be a final lesson, it should be that even when prototyping, writing clear and unambiguous code is important.